# HQL - EntityManager.createQuery throws NPE on CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-entitymanager

I'm trying to create a SELECT query with columns from multiple SELECT statements, however it's been failing with an NPE. Below is the query and then the stack trace. Thanks for any help!

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT " +
        "(SELECT count(*) AS totalPlayers FROM TeamEntity t, AssignmentsEntity a, JerseyEntity p " +
        "WHERE t.id = a.teamid AND p.jerseyId = a.jerseyid and t.id = :teamId), " +
        "(SELECT count(*) AS activePlayers FROM TeamEntity t2, AssignmentsEntity a2, JerseyEntity " +
        "WHERE t2.id = a2.teamid AND JerseyEntity.jerseyid = a2.jerseyid AND t2.id = :teamId " +
        "AND starttime > 0) " +
        "FROM TeamEntity");

query.setParameter("teamId", teamId);

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1192)
    at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1186)
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(TreeMap.java:376)
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:345)
    at java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionRegistry.findSQLFunction(SQLFunctionRegistry.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findSQLFunction(SessionFactoryHelper.java:385)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode.getDataType(IdentNode.java:374)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.lookupProperty(HqlSqlWalker.java:659)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5002)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1286)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4174)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2138)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2066)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2063)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2063)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:815)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:609)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2466)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2232)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1503)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:585)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:706)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:731)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact solution I was looking for, but I just used em.createNativeQuery() and this did the trick for me. Hopefully it doesn't cause any trouble down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT " +
        "(SELECT count(*) AS totalPlayers FROM TeamEntity t, AssignmentsEntity a, JerseyEntity p " +
        "WHERE t.id = a.teamid AND p.jerseyId = a.jerseyid and t.id = :teamId), " +
        "(SELECT count(*) AS activePlayers FROM TeamEntity t2, AssignmentsEntity a2, JerseyEntity p " +
        "WHERE t2.id = a2.teamid AND p.jerseyid = a2.jerseyid AND t2.id = :teamId " +
        "AND starttime > 0) " +
        "FROM TeamEntity");
```